# use $scope Variable into a function

Tags: angularjs, scope

How can i use $scope into a function

my code is  and $scope.products do not work:

```
     $http.get('catalog/view/theme/default/template/confirm/fetch_product.php').then(function(response){ $scope.products = response.data.records; });
$scope.items = [];
var counter = 0;
$scope.loadMore = function($scope) {
    var last = $scope.products.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(counter >= last) { break; }
         $scope.items.push($scope.products[counter]);
        counter += 1;
    }
};
$scope.loadMore();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$scope` function from `loadMore` function. It is killing existence of controller `$scope` & inside `loadMore` function `$scope` will be undefined.

```
$scope.loadMore = function($scope) { //<== remove `$scope` from function parameter
```

Also you can't get `$scope.products` object because you are calling `loadMore` method as soon as your controller get initialize. I think you should wait till initial collection of `$http.get` loads `$scope.products` & inside `.then` you should be calling `$scope.loadMore();` function.

Comment: i did it my code is now : $scope.loadMore = function() { but still i cant use $scope.products in function

Comment: Yeah Thanks a lot